# MATLAB fminsearch optimization error

Tags: matlab

I want to optimize x value in the following equation

```
formula_1=((x(1)+x(2).*exp(-TR./x(3)))./(1+cos(time_stamps).* exp(-TR./x(3))));
diff =@(x)sum((formula_1-img_vol).^2);

[pa,fval,exfl]= fminsearch(diff,startingvals,opts);

startingvals=[1,1,0.1];

opts = optimset('Display','off','TolFun',1e-9,'TolX',1e-9);

img_vol = 32x32x11 vector.
```

**These all I am doing in the main script file. But the error comes out is**

```
Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in biexp_main (line 65)
            [pa,fval,exfl]=fminsearch(diff,startingvals,opts);
```

Kindly help me what I suppose to do??

Comment: I think you are leaving out some of the error message. It should tell you the error as well as its location.

Comment: Your objective function is not a function of `x`.

Comment: error is in the location of fav(:,1)= funfcn(x,varagin{:});   and formula_1 contains the x values. it is indirectly contributing in diff.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to reproduce your error since there is many information missing. (What is the exact error? What are the sizes of `TR` and `time_stamps`?).

What should help is:

- change your function `diff` so that it returns a scalar if this is currently not the case (check with `diff(startginvals)`). Maybe change it to `sum(sum(sum(.)))`.
- As indicated in the comments: `diff` is independent from `x` in the current form. The 'indirect contribution' you mention does not work: it considers `formula_1` and hence `x` as constant.

Putting this together, try:

```
TR = rand; %?
time_stamps = rand; %?
img_vol = rand(32,32,11);

formula_1 = @(x) (x(1)+x(2).*exp(-TR./x(3))) ./ (1+cos(time_stamps).*exp(-TR./x(3)));
diff = @(x) sum(sum(sum((formula_1(x)-img_vol).^2)));

opts = optimset('Display','off','TolFun',1e-9,'TolX',1e-9);
startingvals=[1,1,0.1];

[xOpt,diffOpt] = fminsearch(diff,startingvals,opts);
```